# How can I launch Chrome with flags from command line more concisely?

Tags: macos, command-line, security, webgl, shortcut

I am developing a WebGL driven application and I want to launch chrome like this from the command line:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

I just don't want to have to type that in every single time. Is there a way to easily turn that into a one word command? I am using a mac if it matters.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just make an alias in your .bashrc or .bash_profile

```
alias ogc='open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security'
```

And then reload your shell.

```
exec $SHELL
```

Now, every time you type `ogc` (or whatever you want to call it) in your terminal, it will run the full command `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`

Comment: I get bash: export: `–args': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `–disable-web-security': not a valid identifier
when I try to run exec $SHELL

Comment: That should be two dashes. It also sounds like you added it to your $PATH somehow, which you don't need to do. The line I added in the comment is all you need. See the examples in my dotfile repo. https://github.com/kevinSuttle/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/aliases.zsh Just add them to the bottom of your .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: I just used your tip to open Chrome Canary 73 in Mojave dark mode: `open -a Google\ Chrome\ Canary --args --force-dark-mode`

Comment: that just moves the focus to chrome if chrome is already open

Answer (score 10):

This work for me:

1. Modify the .bash_profile
2. Write this alias:

```
alias cchrome='/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security'
```

3. Run

```
exec $SHELL
```

4. With the `cchrome` command open a new windows of chrome with the disable web security to solve the "access-control-allow-origin" problem

Answer (score 5):

The Easiest way to Launch Chrome with flags in MAC using terminal is :

`'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating`

Any filter can come after `--` in the above code `--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating` is just an example.

Note: Make sure to close all instances of Chrome before running it.

Answer (score -5):

Why not just run a webserver? Open a terminal and type

```
cd folder_with_html_and_assets
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now in your browser to go `http://localhost:8000`  When your done go to the terminal and press Ctrl-C

That seems much better than disabling your security and risking getting pwnd.

Comment: the npm package http-server is also very convenient.  `npm install http-server`

Comment: No one is getting pwnd. He's doing development. Maybe a quick search would be appropriate to verify your statements first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: Maybe you should research why that restriction was added in the first place.