# Chrome disable SSL checking for sites?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I'm getting this warning for visiting non https site as https

[image]

Tried this to disable it by adding that command to shortcut target, but it doesnt work.

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests**

Is there any possible method to disable ssl check for websites ?

Comment: Disabling the certificate check destroys the security of SSL.  Don't do that.

Comment: I know, but need to do it for our project before it will be published.

Comment: Also see [Why am I suddenly getting a “Blocked loading mixed active content” issue in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18251128/608639). [Mixed content causes specific browser behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-mixed-content-20140722/) per the W3C.

Answer (score 75):

To disable the errors windows related with certificates you can start Chrome from console and use this option: `--ignore-certificate-errors`.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors
```

You should use it for testing purposes. A more complete list of options is here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Link to launching Chrome in OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146125/how-can-i-launch-chrome-with-flags-from-command-line-more-concisely

Comment: doesn't help in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116

Comment: Works! But doble check  all your chrome windows / tabs are closed before running!! ... Or it will not work

Comment: If you also add: `--user-data-dir="%TEMP%"` (or any other dir), you don't need to close other chrome instances to make it work.

Comment: I am getting NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H15) and Chrome Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (x86_64).  Above solution does not help.

Comment: Also works for Opera browser!

Comment: Thanks @JoséAntonioPostigo ! I was having trouble to listed to online radio where only the certificate used by the stream was invalid and your solution works!

Answer (score 23):

Mac Users please execute the below command from terminal to disable the certificate warning.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests &> /dev/null
```

Note that this will also have Google Chrome mark all HTTPS sites as insecure in the URL bar.

Comment: this works, but the spaces are not escaped in your answer use this `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors`

Comment: this should be ```open -a Google\ Chrome --args --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests```

Comment: Thanks!
`--ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests` also seems to be working on Ubuntu.

Comment: These errors are there for a reason... Globally disabling them seems like a really bad idea...

Comment: Working on Chrome 92 on Windows 10 20H2. Altough Chrome warns "this is a bad idea", broken HTTPS sites can be displayed.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was developing an ASP.Net MVC5 web app and the certificate errors on my local dev machine (IISExpress certificate) started becoming a practical concern once I started working with **service workers**. Chrome simply wouldn't register my service worker because of the certificate error.

I did, however, notice that during my automated Selenium browser tests, Chrome seem to just "ignore" all these kinds of problems (e.g. the warning page about an insecure site), so I asked myself the question: *How is Selenium starting Chrome for running its tests, and might it also solve the service worker problem?*

Using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) on Windows, I was able to find out the command-line arguments with which Selenium is starting Chrome:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12207 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\some-non-existent-directory" data:,
```

There are a bunch of parameters here that I didn't end up doing necessity-testing for, but if I run Chrome this way, my service worker registers and works as expected.

The only one that does seem to make a difference is the *--user-data-dir* parameter, which to make things work can be set to a non-existent directory (things won't work if you don't provide the parameter).

Hope that helps someone else with a similar problem. I'm using Chrome 60.0.3112.90.

Comment: Seems like the `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag might also be a relevant one.